# Simulate AS2 _global variable using a simple class in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I have recently started making (and am still making) the transition from ActionScript 2 to 3. I have used the _global variable in an AS2 project as I needed a variable to be accessible from within ANY swf loaded into my main movie. This worked like a treat.

However, along came AS3 and whipped that from right under my feet. After much Googling, a few people suggested making use of a simple class with a simple variable that can be publicly set and retrieved. I made a simple class, imported it and manipulated the value, and all went well, however the instance of the class I create in my main loader movie is still not accessible from within a second SWF that gets loaded into my movie. If I re-instantiate the class in the SWF that is being dynamically loaded, the value reverts to the default value in the class code, not the new value set in my parent (first) movie.

Here is my class code, stored in an external .as file, is there any way I can simulate the ostype variable being a global variable?

```
package{
    public class ostype {
        public var ismac:Boolean = false;
        public function returnOs(){
            return ismac;
        }
    }
}
```

If it helps to know the context of the code, it's used as a simple identifier as to what operating system this flash app is being used on (mac or windows) and as a result let's me server content - such as saving files - in a different manner.

Thanks for any guidance.

Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use static variables:

```
package {
    class GlobalVars {
        public static var isMac:Boolean = false;
    }
}
```

You can then access any member like this: `GlobalVars.isMac = true;`.

Also, you could have a static function returning the OS (although [Capabilities.os](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#os) should do the trick for you).

Comment: Hello weltraumpirat, thank \s for your reply. I have a separate swf called videos.swf loading into a container element in my main.swf movie. The default value for isMac is false, however, if I set it to true from within main.swf, how do I get that value from within video.swf?? It keeps giving me the default false value declared inside the class. Or is that because my function is returning the variable within a function scope?

Comment: Use getDefinitionByName("GlobalVars") from within videos.swf.  http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName()

Comment: Or create an instance variable globals instead of the class I described, and expose it via an interface to videos.swf.  Or put globals in the root object of your main.swf and use stage.getChildAt(0)["globals"] from within videos.swf.  ;)

Comment: It actually worked a treat as you had it in your reply, thank you. I was creating a new instance of the class in both swf's that's why. By simply typing ostype.isMac = true; in my main container SWF file and then testing it by tracing ostype.isMac in a dynamically loaded swf, the value remained true as opposed to the default false. Thanks a ton, you helped a bunch. This is one of those small invaluable lessons I'll carry with me for many a project. Big up to you.